# Datatables and django template. _DT_CellIndex error

Tags: jquery, html, templates, datatables

i have a problem with my table. I use Datatables, and trying make hidden child rows.

Console log show me error:

> jquery.dataTables.min.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

I am already read about it, and find that problem maybe in incorrect table header or footer, in different count of `<th>` in head and `<td>` in body.

Or maybe problem in `colspan, rowspan`, i don`t know.

And i`m use django template for build parts of my table, this makes all more complicated.

Ok, now i show you table:

```
<table id="ordersTable" class="hover dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" style="width: 100%;">
          <thead>
            <tr role="row">
              <th class="details-control sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 18px;"></th>
              <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ordersTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending"  style="width: 136px;">№</th>
              <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ordersTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1"  style="width: 217px;">Дата</th>
              <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ordersTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1"  style="width: 101px;">Статус</th>
              <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ordersTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1"  style="width: 43px;">Доставка</th>
              <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ordersTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1"  style="width: 91px;">Оплата</th>
              <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ordersTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1"  style="width: 79px;">Итого</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th class="details-control sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 18px;"></th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">№</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Дата</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Статус</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Доставка</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Оплата</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Итого</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            {% for k, order in shop.retail.orders.items %}

                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
                    <tr role="row" class="even">
                {% else %}
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                {% endif %}

                {% for order_elem in order %}
                  <td class=" details-control "></td>
                  <td class="sorting_1">
                        {{ order_elem.id }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        {{ order_elem.created_at }}
                  </td>
                  <td>                
                        {{ order_elem.status_id }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        {{ order_elem.delivery_name }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        {{ order_elem.payment_id }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        {{ order_elem.total_price_with_discount }} грн
                  </td>
                  </tr>

                    {% for k, order in shop.retail.ord_items.items %}
                          <tr style="display:none;">
                          <td>
                          <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">
                              <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td style="width: 60px;">Артикул:</td>
                                  <td style="width: 317px;">Название:</td>
                                  <td style="width: 101px;">Количество:</td>
                                  <td style="width: 43px;">Сумма:</td>
                              </tr>
                              {% for value in order %}
                              {% if value.order_id == order_elem.id %}

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 60px;"> <a href="/{{ value.slug }}"> {{ value.article }} </a> </td>
                                    <td style="width: 517px;"> <a href="/{{ value.slug }}"> {{ value.name }} </a> </td>
                                    <td style="width: 101px;"> <a href="/{{ value.slug }}"> {{ value.count }} </a> </td>
                                    <td style="width: 43px;"> <a href="/{{ value.slug }}"> {{ value.total_price_with_discount }} </a> </td>
                                </tr>

                              {% endif %}
                              {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          </td>
                          <tr>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here some js code for this table, but i think it`s not necessary:

```
var table = $('#ordersTable').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "Все"]],
    "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/i18n/Russian.json"
        }
} );
```

Code that show-hide child rows:

```
    $('#ordersTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child.show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You have opening tag `<tr>` at the end instead of closing tag `</tr>`.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com yes, thanx, but its not helped =(

Comment: I found that problem in <tr><td></td></tr> that wrapped the table, when remove it - no errors, but wrong table structure.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com  - not work.

Comment: I suddenly realized that you're creating child rows manually, instead you should follow [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) and avoid creating HTML markup for child rows manually.